# How can I limit the number of upload files programmatically?

Tags: entities, files

I need to limit the number of upload files programmatically because the max number of files is 10 or unlimited and I need 14 upload files. Is it possible? I found the [Upload max files](http://drupal.org/project/upload_maxfiles) module, but my question is if it is possible, programmatically.

I have installed Drupal 6.

Comment: What do you mean by "programmatically"? If I understand your question correctly, why would you like to write a custom code instead of reusing existing contrib module? What Drupal core version are you using?

Comment: My version of Drupal is 6.  This module allows limit of number of upload per node.  If in my content type I have two fields:  photos and images.  Photos field have 12 upload files and Images field have 15 upload files.  The module allows put of limit 25 upload files but not allows restrict the number of upload files for each field.  I'm sorry my english.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The patch reported in [Add a custom 'number of values' for 'multiple/ multi-value' field. (e.g. nodereference, image field)](http://drupal.org/node/680546) can be useful to solve your requirement. (It has been tested with Drupal 6.20.)

Answer (score 1):

I assume you use filefield module for attachment, if so, use this:

```
/**
 * Implementation of hook_form_alter().
 */
function YOURMODULENAME_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id == 'content_field_edit_form') {
    $form['field']['multiple']['#options'] = array(1 => t('Unlimited'), 0 => 1) + drupal_map_assoc(range(2, 14));
  }
}
```

Comment: I put this code but I can't see any changes.

I put the name of field:  field_images in 'field'.

Comment: Edit your field.

Comment: I edited the field and I can't see any changes.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: Let's do next: add drupal_set_message($form_id); above row: if ($form_id ==)... Then refresh field editing, what value it's show?

Comment: I put:
$form_id == 'story_edit_form'
field == field_images
YOUR MODULE == mymodule.  Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: I put: $form_id == 'story_edit_form' field == field_images YOUR MODULE == mymodule and I can't to see changes. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Ah, it doesn't story editing, it's CCK field editing.

Comment: I'll try again and I will comment to you.

Comment: ok, waiting it...